# Mazda 3 wont start

Tags: starting, mazda-3

I owe `Mazda 3 4 door AT 2011 model Gasoline Engine`, and I have got it second hand. The total Kilometers on the dash is around `20K`. Last night I drove may car from my office to home which is around `4KM`, today morning when I am trying to start the car its not starting.
I don't recall `Low engine Oil Pressure` warning last night when I drove back home, but today, I can see `Low Engine Oil Pressure` is flashing. The `battery` seems to be ok, as `lights`, `AC`, `music system` all are working fine. The `oil gauge` shows that the engine oil is low, and I was planning to change oil today. I don't recall any `burning smell` due to low engine oil, or heavy engine sound last night when I drove back. Few days back when I had a drag issue (accelerating power drops), and when I got it checked they told me its a spark plug issue and needs to be replaced.

Is it because of low engine oil pressure the car is not starting up? (is it so automated in mazda 3 that car wont start?)
What can be other troubleshooting items for me?

Regards,
Y

Comment: Is the starter motor turning the engine over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got It fixed today, the main problem was the Battery (Didn't realize until I took it to a service center). Regarding my questions

1. Is it because of low engine oil pressure the car is not starting up?
   Is it so automated in mazda 3 that car wont start?
   Well No, the model which I have at-least does not have this automatic feature to stop the car engine immediately, you need to be careful about the engine oil pressure level, and if you see the warning signal on your dashboard, stop the car immediately (what the service center guy suggested me)

The only part which was difficult to digest was the fact that the lights and A/c etc was working perfectly fine (as if the battery was really powerful)

Also post replacing the battery I don't feel the drag issue(accelerating power drops) as well.

Thank you all for the help